# Erro no Setup.exe do Sql server 2016 developer x 64

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Baixei o arquivo ISO do SQL Server, montei e na hora de clicar no setup.exe acontece esse erro. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Preciso instalar o SQL Server pra usar junto com o visual studio. Fá desinstalei tudo e tentei instalar novamente, limpei tudo que era referente ao SQL Server no notebook, até na barra de pesquisa não aparecer nada quando digitado "sql".

Também já usei outra versão do SQL Server, e sempre dá o mesmo erro.

Uso Windows 10 pro, 1 TB, 8 GB RAM X64.

Comment: tentou baixar novamente?

Comment: Sim.Já baixei até outra versões diferentes pra ver se funcionava, e o mesmo erro persiste...

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisando o que pode estar acontecendo encontrei essa pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164506/error-with-no-information-when-installing-sql-server-2012-on-vmware-virtual-serv

Aparentemente é um problema na sua ISO, tente baixar novamente a partir de outro computador. Tente montar a ISO de uma forma diferente também.

Você pode investigar com mais detalhes nos [logs de instalação do SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files). No SQL Server 2016 esse log está disponível em `%programfiles%\ Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log`

Comment: Ok.Farei isso, logo mais dou um retorno.